# status code 500 internal server error in LoadRunner

Tags: load-testing, loadrunner

I have a web application which i need to be load tested using LoadRunner. When I record the website using vugen it works good and there is no any application bug. But when I tried to replay the script, script failed after login and while navigating to next page, say, Transaction. At the end of log, I receive error:

```
Action.c(252): Error -26612: HTTP Status-Code=500 (Internal Server Error) 
for "http://rob.com/common/transaction
```

Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Are you replaying in vugen or controller?

Comment: Are there any errors **before** that error?

Answer (score 2):

LoadRunner generates HTTP request just as your browser does, this error is the same error you would get if you would go to that URL using your browser. Error code 500 is a generic server error that is returned when there is no better (more specific error to return). 
Most likely the login process requires some form of authentication which is protected against a replay attack by using some form of token. It is up to you to capture this token using Correlations in LoadRunner and replay it as the server expects. The Correlation Studio in VuGen should detect and identify the token for you but since authentication methods vary it is sometimes impossible to do this automatically and you will have to create manual correlation. Please consult the product documentation for more details on how to do it. If your website is publicly available online then post its URL and I will try to record the script on my machine.

Thanks,
Boris.

Answer (score 2):

Most common reasons

1. You are not checking each request for a valid result being returned and using a 200 HTTP status as an assumed correct step without examining the content of what is being returned.   As a result when data being returned is incorrect you are not branching the code to handle the exception.   Go one to two steps beyond where your business process has come off the rails with an assumptive success and you will have a 500 status message for an out of context action occurring 100% of the time.
2. Missed dynamic element.   Record three times.  Compare the code.  Address the changing components.